# Display a PDF file from SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I already uploaded PDF files into my SQL Server database as binary data file. I want to retrieve this file and open it with Adobe Reader on my form.

Please help; I am using Visual Studio 2015

Thanks in advance.

I try this but still no results:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DEFAUTHEQUE def = new DEFAUTHEQUE();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from articles where matricule_article='" + textBox3.Text + "'", con);

     SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (read.Read())
     {
         if (!read.IsDBNull(read.GetOrdinal("fiche_cond")))
         {
             byte[] pa = (byte[])read["fiche_cond"];
             File.WriteAllBytes("file.pdf", pa);

             string path = @"C:\Users\faten\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\application_microtechnic-270418-14h43\application_microtechnic-270418-14h43\Resources\file.pdf";
             def.axAcroPDF1.src = path;
         }
      }

      read.Close();
      def.Show();
  }
```

and this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DEFAUTHEQUE def = new DEFAUTHEQUE();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string path = @"C: \Users\faten\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\file.pdf";

    using (SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from articles where matricule_article='eee'", con))
    {
        cmd.Fill(ds);
        string s = textBox3.Text;
        int c = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fiche_cond"];

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);

        def.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(path);
    }

    def.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: “please heeeellp” is not a question we can answer. The first thing you need to do is learn how to [parameterize queries](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx). Then you need to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: sorry am beginner ,but  this code run without errors !!

Comment: The samples I see lying around also do axAcroPDF1.Visible = true;

Comment: @KyleHuff done!  , the axAcroPDF1 shown correctly !but it display nothing

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Delcaring def in an event handler seems wrong.  It is going out of scope immediately.  Shouldn't this be something on your form?

Comment: @KyleHuff sorry i don't understand what u mean ! can u explain more

Comment: @faten loued Your PDF rendering control needs to be persistent.  You are creating a new local object for it inside the event handler that goes out of scope and is orphaned on return.  It will get garbage collected at some point beyond your control.

Comment: @KyleHuff ah okey thnx

Answer (score -5):

txtIDCarr.Text = Convert.ToString(datagrv.Cells[0].Value);
tbl.Clear();
tbl = db.readData("SELECT[ID_cr_arr],[courrierArr].[ID_documents],[ID_user],[N_courrier],[date_corr],[date_res],[Expediteur],[service],[sujet],[observation],[boîte],[attachName],[attachment],[filetype] FROM[courrierArr],[documents] where[courrierArr].[ID_documents] =[documents].[ID_documents] and [ID_cr_arr]='"+txtIDCarr.Text.Trim()+"'", "");

```
            txtIDCarr.Text = tbl.Rows[row1][0].ToString();
            txtIDDOC.Text =(Convert.ToInt32( tbl.Rows[row1][1])).ToString();
            txtname_user.Text = tbl.Rows[row1][2].ToString();
            txtncrr.Text = tbl.Rows[row1][3].ToString();
                    byte[] ap = (byte[]) tbl.Rows[row1][12];
                    string tempName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf");
                    File.WriteAllBytes(tempName, ap);
                    axAcroPDF1.src = tempName;
```

Comment: this answer needs to be formatted correctly and could use some documentation of what it is doing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).